# Using Highlight JS in Angular 2

Tags: angular, highlight

I'm trying to use Highlight JS in my Angular 2 app, and am having some trouble figuring out how to use it, when the codeblock is not static information. What I mean is, the code string comes from the server through an http get call.

So, if I have this:

```
export  class   WorkstationComponent implements OnInit  {

    private submission = new Submission();
    private criteria = new Array<ExerciseCriteria>();
    private codeString:string = `
        /* HelloWorld.java
        */

        public class HelloWorld
        {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        }`;

    constructor(private _router:Router, private submissionService:SubmissionService,
                private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute){}

    @ViewChild('code') codeElement: ElementRef;

ngOnInit(){
    this.activatedRoute.params
        // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.submissionService.getSubmission(+params['id']))
        .subscribe(data => this.success(data),
                    error => this.fail(error));

}

success(data:any){
    this.submission = data;
    this.criteria = data.criteria;
    hljs.highlightBlock(this.codeElement.nativeElement);
}
```

There is no problem...

[image: success]

However, if i change to

```
success(data:any){
    this.submission = data;
    this.criteria = data.criteria;
    this.codeString = data.code;
    hljs.highlightBlock(this.codeElement.nativeElement);
}
```

I get this:

[image: fail]

What am I doing wrong?
The HTML is the same

```
                <pre>
                    <code #code highlight class="java">
                        {{codeString}}
                    </code>
                </pre>
```

Comment: My guess is `highlightBlock` is getting fire before `codeString` binding gets evaluated. You might need to wait for next tick and call `highlightBlock` function. Like by doing `setTimeout(() => { hljs.highlightBlock(this.codeElement.nativeElement); },0);` instead of `hljs.highlightBlock(this.codeElement.nativeElement);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because `highlightBlock` function is getting fire before the inner `code` element content isn't available. One of the solution to do is `setTimeout` to make apply `highlightBlock` one tick later once all binding gets applied. But unnecessarily that will make run another change detection.

Better rather than waiting for inner content to bounded on DOM, you could manually applied it to textContent of DOM and then apply `highlightBlock` function.

**Code**

```
success(data:any){
    this.submission = data;
    this.criteria = data.criteria;
    this.codeString = data.code;
    //making sure code is populated by below line
    this.codeElement.nativeElement.textContent = data.code;
    hljs.highlightBlock(this.codeElement.nativeElement);
}
```

Comment: The setTimeout approach worked for me.

Getting error "this.codeElement.nativeElement.textContent is not a function" with the second approach.

Comment: @ManuelZamith Ahh.. textContent is property not a method (I mistakenly had method there :().. check updated answer, it should work  :)

Comment: Brilliant :) . Thank you so much.

Comment: @ManuelZamith no worries, Its my hobby to help people :-)

Answer (score 1):

In Angular4, to use highlight.js from component:

```js
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import * as hljs from 'highlight.js';

@Component({
    selector: 'cus-com',
    template: `
    <pre>
        <code [innerHtml]="html_content"></code>
    </pre>`,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styles: [require('highlight.js/styles/github.css')]
})
export class CustomComponentsComponent {
    languages = ['html', 'typescript'];
    html_content = hljs.highlightAuto('<h1 class="big">Title</h1>', this.languages).value;  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in @PankajParkar comment, `highlightBlock` is getting fire before `codeString` binding gets evaluated.

Deferring running this function to the next tick (using `setTimeout`) will work as it will allow Angular to do change detection and DOM update.

The alternative solution is to use Pipe. Here is Pipe I use for code highlighting using [Prism.js](http://prismjs.com/). You can easily update it to use Highlight.js:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'prism' })
export class PrismPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value, args) {
    if (!isString(value)) {
      throw new InvalidPipeArgumentException(PrismPipe, value);
    }
    let lang = args[0].toString().trim().toLowerCase();

    let grammar = Prism.languages[lang];
    // fallback to clike
    if (!grammar) grammar = Prism.languages.clike;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(Prism.highlight(value, grammar));
  }
}
```

Then I use it in code like this:

```
<pre [innerHtml]="codeString.source | prism:codeString.lang"></pre>
```